# MYSQL Left Join COUNTS AND SUMS from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, count, sum

I have tried looking for similar questions here in SO and have not found any so far. Feel free to tag the duplicate or similar question to this one if you'd like.

I want to join several columns to display a report.

I have 3 tables.

**Users**

```
ID  Name
1   Chris
2   John
3   Rick
```

**InMessages**

```
ID  Content   
1   Hello1
2   Hello2
3   Response1
4   Response2
5   Hello3
6   Hello4
```

**OutMessages**

```
ID UserID InMessageID Content         CurrentRate
1  1      1           ReplyHello1     10
2  2      2           Reply1Hello2    10   
3  3      2           Reply2Hello2    10
4  3      2           Reply3Hello2    10
5  1      3           ReplyResponse1  10
6  2      4           ReplyResponse2  10
7  1      5           ReplyHello3     4
8  3      6           ReplyHello4     4
```

And the report I'd like to see would be something like:

```
User   InMessagesCount OutMessagesCount Rate10 Rate4
Chris  3               3                2      1     
John   2               2                1      1
Rick   2               3                2      1
```

I have tried the existing queries like:

```
  count(distinct InMessages.ID) as InMessagesCount,
  count(distinct OutMessages.ID) as OutMessagesCount
```

But I am stuck as to how I could make the one for the rates.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You issue seems to be that your multiple joins are creating duplicate records, hence needing DISTINCT in your current counts. But you can't use that for counting the number of occurrences of a non distinct field

As such I would be tempted to try something like this:-

```
COUNT(DISTINCT IF(OutMessages.CurrentRate = 10, OutMessages.ID, NULL) ) AS Rate10,
COUNT(DISTINCT IF(OutMessages.CurrentRate = 4, OutMessages.ID, NULL) ) AS Rate4
```

Ie, if the id is 10 then use the id, otherwise use NULL. COUNT like this should (I think) only count the non null values.

Comment: that's the problem I am facing right now. because the joins return more than what is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

For Mysql you can use `sum()` with expression so it will evaluate as a count that you need for your 2 rates

```
select 
u.Name,
count(distinct o.InMessageID) as InMessagesCount,
count(distinct o.ID) as OutMessagesCount,
sum(o.CurrentRate = 10) rate10,
sum(o.CurrentRate = 4) rate10
from OutMessages o
joins  users u on(u.id = o.user_id)
group by  u.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sum up those records that match a specific rate:

```
SUM(IF(OutMessages.CurrentRate = 10, 1,0)) AS Rate10,
SUM(IF(OutMessages.CurrentRate = 4, 1,0)) AS Rate4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IF` and `SUM`, like this:

```
SELECT UserID,
       COUNT(DISTINCT InMessages.ID) AS InMessagesCount,
       COUNT(DISTINCT OutMessages.ID) AS OutMessagesCount,
       SUM(IF(OutMessages.CurrentRate = 10, 1, 0)) AS Rate10,
       SUM(IF(OutMessages.CurrentRate = 4, 1, 0)) AS Rate4
FROM OutMessages
GROUP BY UserID
```